# How to assign a key remapping to specific device using hidutil

Tags: macos

As seen in [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html) from Apple, you can remap a key from the command line in OS Sierra with something like:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping": 
  [{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000054,
    "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000067
  }]
}'
```

Is it possible to assign this change only to a specific keyboard device, e.g. if you want to map one device to the output of a second, but not affect the function of the second?

The article is no longer updated and there appears to be no current documentation of how the command works.

Comment: When you have multiple keyboards attached, do you get multiple lines from `hidutil dump services | grep AppleHIDKeyboardEventDriver`?

Comment: Only one line : `<string>AppleHIDKeyboardEventDriver</string>`

Comment: Hmm. I'm not certain, but that suggests that there's only the one service, no matter the number of keyboards, and so there's only one user key mapping. Also, from that technote: "Key remappings are lost when the system is restarted or if the keyboard service is removed (for example when the last keyboard is disconnected.)" That also suggests that there's just the one service for all keyboards and the mapping resides with it.

Answer (score 20):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "if you want to map one device to the output of a second, but not affect the function of the second?", but the rest of your question sounds like you just want to remap a specific external device. This can be accomplished with the following command:

```
hidutil property --matching '{"ProductID":0x123}' --set '{"UserKeyMapping": 
 [{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000054,
   "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000067
 }]
}'
```

You'll need to determine your specific ProductID and insert it into the command above. You can find ProductIDs for internal and external devices at the following location:

```
Apple icon > About This Mac > System Report > USB (under Hardware section in left panel)
```

These changes will be reverted after each restart. In order to make this fix permanent, follow the solution provided in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329085/tilde-and-plus-minus-%C2%B1-in-wrong-place-on-keyboard/353941#353941).

Comment: Great, thanks ! Works perfectly to solve mapping issues with external keyboards.

Comment: [Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/353941/318739) there's also an explanation of how to make this change persistent across reboots

Comment: You can get a list of all the input devices with ProductID and other properties you can use for matching with `hidutil list`. See also `hidutil property --help` for some examples on property matching

Comment: Can I set this command multiple times for different product ids?

Comment: Should this work for remapping only keys on the internal keyboard as well? I manage to find the product id of the internal keyboard on  SPI, but using this command is not working for me